# Database design for school management to keep track of current and previous school years

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's the best way to design a students registration records and keep tracks of previous academic years?
I have a table to enroll students, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students] (
    [StudentID]          INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentNumber]      NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,    
    [EnrolmentDate]      DATE            NULL,
    [Class]              NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [StudentSurname]     NVARCHAR (60)   NOT NULL,
    [StudentFirstNames]  NVARCHAR (60)   NOT NULL, 
    [FatherSurname]      NVARCHAR (100)  NULL,
    [FatherNames]        NVARCHAR (100)  NULL,    
    [MotherSurname]      NVARCHAR (100)  NULL,
    [MotherNames]        NVARCHAR (100)  NULL,
    [SchoolYear]         NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL, 
    [StudentPicture]     VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_Students] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([StudentNumber] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_AcademicYear] FOREIGN KEY ([SchoolYear]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AcademicYear] ([SchoolYear]) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I also have other tables for SchoolFees, MarksEntry, SchoolYear, etc.
So far everything works well for current year, I an just select where SchoolYear = current year, whether it's list of students, ,marks or fees paid/unpaid.

The challenge is to access data from previous years, I haven't figured out how to design the database or add a column to keep track of previous year.
When a student passes the exam, he/she promoted to a different class, so what I update in the Students table is: Class and SchoolYear, the rest of data remain the same like student number and other details.
So if I have a student in class 1B in school year 2020-2021 and promote to class 2B in year 2021-2022, the records of this student in class 1B in 2020-2021 are still in database but no longer accessible because that student no longer exist, their records have been modified.
What's the best and easy solution not to duplicate a student records but somewhat keep track of previous classes and school years when promoting a student to a different class?

Comment: There's no functional dependency between StudentID and SchoolYear.  That's a clue that this table is not your "Student" table, it's "StudentSchoolYear" or somesuch, and the PK should be (StudentID,SchoolYear).  Immutable attributes of the Student can be migrated to the new "Student" table.

Comment: I don't understand? The schoolYear table only records the period. CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AcademicYear] (
    [SchoolYear] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AcademicYear] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SchoolYear] ASC)
);

Comment: To add to what @DavidBrowne-Microsoft says, the column `[Class]` should refer to (`FOREIGN KEY`) `ClassId` column in the `Classes` table. Please next time use the `database` tag when you 've a Q about designing a database.

Comment: Might be better asked on sister site, DBA Stack Exchange.

Comment: You need to normalize this table, you would have `Student`, `StudentYear`, `Year` tables. And do think better about your data types, there is no reason for `SchoolYear` to be `nvarchar(50)` it should be either `date` or `smallint`

Comment: The school year is not int because the format is: 2020-2021.